# Stopping Javascript or Mouse events "IE ActiveX"

Tags: javascript, jquery, delphi, mshtml, twebbrowser

I have a html page being loaded into an IE activex "webbrowser object", this page uses jquery that performs various modification actions on the elements. I need to stop the jquery or javascript action on the html page to perform some functions that list the elements.

If this is not possible, stopping mouse events will resolve the issue.

How do I stop the javascript or mouse events from working on an html page?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To stop mouse,key board press event, you just need to follow below steps:

1. Create a js function as follows:

   function stopEventsOnBodyLoad()
   {

   ```
   window.oncontextmenu = function () {
       return false;
   }

   window.onkeydown = function () {
       return false;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Invoke this method on body onload